# query to select only the timestamp each 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if it's possible to have a query that will retrieve all the data with the Timestamp is a multiple of 5 minutes for example. (00h00, 00h05, 00h10, etc...)

Here's my query :

```
SELECT io_data.Timestamp, io.Name AS ioName, io_data.ReadingValue
FROM io_data io
WHERE io_data.Actif = 1 
  AND io.ID_IO_Type = 3
ORDER BY io.Name, io.ID_IO_Type, io_data.Timestamp ASC
```

This is because the system retrieve the value each 3 sec (in some cases) or at each 7.5 sec, 15 sec, 30 sec or 1 minute (in other cases). It depends of the customer settings. But, we I do a chart, that contains too many data and I would like to have only the data for each X minutes (1, 5, 10, etc... minutes)

I can't figure out how can I do that if it's possible.

Comment: Convert to minutes and use [`mod( )`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod).

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert to minutes, just take the `minute` part of the timestamp column:

```
SELECT io.Timestamp, io.Name AS ioName, io.ReadingValue
FROM io_data io
WHERE io.Actif = 1 
  AND io.ID_IO_Type = 3
AND minute(io.TimeStamp) % 5 = 0
ORDER BY io.Name, io.ID_IO_Type, io.Timestamp ASC
```

Comment: It's not working, it takes all the values received at each 3 sec within the minute % 5. So, if I have data each 3 sec at 10h00, 10h05, etc... All the data is retrieved. Ex. 10:00:00, 10:00:03, 10:00:06,...

Comment: This is an old post... However, what do you mean "it is not working"? Where do you specify in your question that all these records should not be retrieved?